# How does IntWritable.class provides an object of IntWritable class

Tags: java, hadoop, serialization

```
public static WritableComparator get(Class<? extends WritableComparable> c)
```

get method in WritableComparator accepts an object of type class as an argument

```
RawComparator<IntWritable> comparator = WritableComparator.get(IntWritable.class);
```

So how does IntWritable.class provides an object of IntWritable class ?

Comment: `IntWritable.class` is the class literal of the class `IntWritable`. It doesn't provide anything (unless you use `newInstance()`).

Answer (score 2):

Based on your question I presume that you are looking for an object which is not visible to you.

Here in the example you are looking for an IntWritable object but you didnt find `NEW` keyword any where in the program.

So to sum it up. How `A.class` is converting into `A a = new A();` ?

To tell you in simple words, you cannot do any thing without having an object in java or hadoop.

Therefore behind the scenes objects are created for the mentioned class for the program execution. At high level we can say that this mechanism is inbuilt in hadoop to take care of object creation on need basis.

And at a little higher level they use `JAVA Reflection API` to do this operations seamlessly under the hood.

Why this is required?
Because we dont know the ANSWERS for following questions in real time:

1. What is the file size?
2. How many input splits (some objects are based on this) ?
3. How many key/value pairs for both INPUT and OUTPUT (some more objects here)?
4. etc. (other objects)

As we dont know

`How many(total number) Objects are needed?` and

`When(execution time in program) they are needed?`

we need to rely on a higher end API like reflection to handle them at runtime.

That `Reflection API used by HADOOP` is responsible to provide the `OBJECT` for the input `CLASS` based on need of the hour.

Hope this clarifies. Explain me if I understood your question wrongly.

Comment: I disagree, you only need one key and value and you also need only one InputFormat. Why does it matter how many outputs it has? That's what the user is creating anyway.

Comment: @pareekrachit, is the provided answer relevant to your view point? respond promptly so that it can be updated.